# Difference between private IP and public IP?

Tags: internet, ip-address

What is the difference between public IP and private IP?
Does each machine have both a private IP and a public IP?
Who assigns public and private IP?
and how can a machine having only a private IP access internet?

Answer (score 2):

The public IP address is known by the internet and the private IP address exists only on your Local Area Network. A classic analogy is that the public IP address is like the physical address of an apartment complex and the private IP addresses are like the individual apartment unit numbers. The internet only sees the overall public address, but your router knows all of your local private IP addresses and can direct things accordingly. So picture the internet (mailman) dropping off a package to the public IP of the router (apartment office) because that's the only address it knows; the router (apartment office) then figures out which computer (apartment unit) the package should go to.

The public address is assigned by your Internet Service Provider. You can find out what yours is by asking "what is my ip?" in a google search. The private IP is assigned by your router and is only local.  A computer with only a private IP may or may not have internet access because the private IP only relates it to the router, which may or may not provide it internet access.

A google search will return many good explanations of these differences.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between public IP and private IP? 
1. Public is globally visible and given to you by your ISP.
2. Private IP is an IP that is only available on your network and can not be reached from the internet directly.

The private IP can be assigned statically or dynamically(dhcp server). 
In order not to conflict with the internet generally these ranges are used.
192.168.0.0/16
172.16.0.0/12
10.0.0.0/8

Also each computer has a 127.0.0.0/8 address which is only for that computer and can not be routed.

In most cases a customer buys a switch/router with built-in NAT and DHCP server.  Every device attached gets an IP handed out by the DHCP server.  The NAT stores a look up table of connections so the incoming connection is matched with the out bound connection that started the connection to a remote server.